# Is my custom encryption handshake secure?

Tags: security, networking, encryption, cryptography

There is some advertisement software I made for a mall, it has a bunch of clients (the screens) and a server from which they derive the content. So far its been working inside a separate LAN so security didn't even cross my mind but they asked me if i could make it manageable over the internet.

I tried coming up with a reasonable solution, something like Plan A

1. Client sends a "I want to log in message"
2. Server responds with a randomly generated key
3. Client sends a password encrypted with said key
4. Server responds with another key, encrypted with the first key
5. Client can now use the last key to encrypd/decrypt any futher communication

But then I got to thinking, whats the point of sending another key? If somebody observing the traffic can figure out the algorithm I'm using then it doesn't matter how many encrypted keys I send if they can just decode them based on the original unencrypted key.

Plan B

1. Client sends user name encrypted with its password

stop right there, then its just a fixed message that would grant access

Plan C

1. Client and Server are given a user/password combination (per user)
2. Each time the client logs in with user encrypted by password (to be used for encrypting all further communication in this session), the server sends a new password so the old one cant be used again

great, except its still suffering from the problem of plan A and brings further problems like what if the clients communication gets cut off right after sending the login and doesn't get the new password...

No matter which way i look at it, if the decryption algorithm is figure-it-outable, there is a hole in the security.

Ok Plan D!

1. Client and Server are given an encryption key by hand
2. Client uses key to encrypt all communication, maybe even requests extra keys to be used in combination with the first one to further complicate decryption

Point is, the original key is never sent over the network.

Ok.. this one seems to work. Obviously anything can be hacked with enough time spent but maybe its enough to make it not worth it. Problem is though, this one is tad clunky and each installation of the client requires a manual entry of the key. Its most likely going to be long and complicated and you're average lazy person would probably just send it over mail which.. meh, purpose defeated.

I don't know what to do at this point. If i could get the same level of security as you're run of the mill login type website (such as this one), that would be fine by me. How do they handle it with just user+password?

Comment: If the server was a rogue spy, you've just given away your [plaintext] password. Also, the "[new] another key" is not secure because any monitor can also see the "original key" it was encrypted with. Security is hard. Use *existing* verified approaches. In this case, search for [cryptography Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange).

Comment: As you have figured out, cryptography is all about the keys. More on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Well, what i got from those 2 is that there is no ultimate answer and based on current technology probably never will be :/ thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use SSL/TLS and a password? Client needs to know the server's public key and the password, once the connection is established you can send the password securely.

Comment: Are you accessing this over a web server?  What is the channel for communication here?

Comment: The 'reasonable solution' already exists. It's called SSL. Use it. Don't try to roll your own. You won't succeed in making it any better than SSL, or in practice anywhere near as good. There is therefore no point in trying. What you've done so far doesn't begin to be secure.

Answer (score 5):

It's admirable that you've put so much thought into this. Now stop right where you are and go use SSL/TLS.  Transport level security abstracts away the need to manually secure your communication channels.  Trying to roll your own key exchange is a Bad Idea (tm) and likely to result in holes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange)? Did you consider asymmetric encryption with [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29), for example?